# Add Show Less to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to add to this current script, to allow a show less also and slide back up to the max of 7. Right now it only has show more and toggle down. It is used to toggle filter groups in a sidebar app for shopify.  Thanks for you help!

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/wzkcraLx/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.filter-group:not(.filter-group-color) ul:not(.has_selected)').each(function(){
      var max = 7;
      if ($(this).find("li:not(.selected)").length > (max+1)) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+(max-1)+'):not(.selected)')
        .hide()
        .end()
        .append(
          $('<li class="view-more-link"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Show More</a></li>').click( function(){
              $(this).siblings(':hidden').slideDown(100).end().slideUp(100);
          })
        );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="filter-group filter-group-aunhgliz has_mutliple_items">
<h4>Size</h4>
<ul class="nav-aunhgliz ">
<li class="collection-container filter-active-size-6mm active ">
<div class="collection-name">
<a title="Narrow selection to products matching tag size-6mm" href="/collections/watch-bands/size-6mm"><i class="check-icon"></i> 6mm</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="collection-container filter-active-size-8mm active ">
<div class="collection-name">
<a title="Narrow selection to products matching tag size-8mm" href="/collections/watch-bands/size-8mm"><i class="check-icon"></i> 8mm</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="collection-container filter-active-size-9mm active ">
<div class="collection-name">
<a title="Narrow selection to products matching tag size-9mm" href="/collections/watch-bands/size-9mm"><i class="check-icon"></i> 9mm</a>
</div>
</li>

</ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all those random (not on fiddle) selectors are but start with this:

```
$(function() {
  var mygroup = $('.filter-group').find('ul');
  var max = 7;
  mygroup.find("li").eq(max).after('<li class="view-more-link"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span class="moreless">Show More</span></a></li>');
  mygroup.find('li.view-more-link').nextAll().hide();
  mygroup.on('click', '.view-more-link', function() {
    if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
      $(this).nextAll().slideUp(100);
      $(this).find('.moreless').text("Show More");
    } else {
      $(this).nextAll().slideDown(100);
      $(this).find('.moreless').text("Show Less");
    }
  });
});
```

Play with it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/wzkcraLx/1/

Comment: It is jargon from the shopify app for filtering https://apps.shopify.com/power-tools-filter-menu, all liquid and html - creating that fiddle tooks some time, hard to create in fiddle.  I tried the script and now there is neither and it shows all

Comment: I pasted my script into your fiddle overwriting your code as a test and it works as I have interpreted what is described as your desired functionality. Other than that I would need some clarification on what should differ from that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked - there must have been a conflict with the shopify app - thanks for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.nav-brand').each(function(){ 
  var LiN = $(this).find('li').length;
  if( LiN > 10){    
    $('li', this).eq(9).nextAll().hide().addClass('extras');
    $(this).append('<li class="more small" style="font-weight:bold;">+ Show More</li>');    
  }
});
$('ul').on('click','.more',function(){
  $this = $(this);
  var text = ($this.text() == '- Show Less') ? '+ Show More' : '- Show Less';
  $this.text(text);  
  $(this).siblings('li.extras').slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
```